# HackerRank "AND product"

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

When I submit the below code for testcases in HackerRank challenge "AND product"...

> You will be given two integers A and B. You are required to compute the bitwise AND amongst all natural numbers lying between A and B, both inclusive.
>
> **Input Format:**
> First line of the input contains T, the number of testcases to follow.
> Each testcase in a newline contains A and B separated by a single space.

```
from math import log
for case in range(int(raw_input())):
    l, u = map(int, (raw_input()).split())
    if log(l, 2) == log(u, 2) or int(log(l,2))!=int(log(l,2)):
        print 0
    else:
        s = ""
        l, u = [x for x in str(bin(l))[2:]], [x for x in str(bin(u))[2:]]
        while len(u)!=len(l):
            u.pop(0)
        Ll = len(l)
        for n in range(0, len(l)):
            if u[n]==l[n]:
                s+=u[n]
        while len(s)!=len(l):
            s+="0"
        print int(s, 2)
```

...it passes 9 of the test cases, Shows "Runtime error" in 1 test case and  shows "Wrong Answer" in the rest 10 of them.

What's wrong in this?

Comment: It is a shame to ask for tips on Stackoverflow about HackerRank problems.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you to use the Bitwise operator in Python for AND. The operator is: '&'

Try this code:

```
def andProduct(a, b):
    j=a+1
    x=a
    while(j<=b):
        x = x&j
        j+=1
    return x
```

For more information on Bitwise operator you can see: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you can do this much faster.
You are doing this very straightforward, calculating all ands in a for loop.

It should actually be possible to calculate this in `O(1)` (I think)

But here are some optimisations:

1) abort the `for` loop if you get the value **0**, because it will stay **0** no matter what

2)If there is a **power of 2** between `l` and `u` `return 0` (you don't need a loop in that case)

My Idea for `O(1)` would be to think about which bits change between `u` and `l`.

Because every bit that changes somewhere between `u` and `l` becomes **0** in the answer.

**EDIT 1:** Here is an answer in `O(same leading digits)` time.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073532/how-to-find-bitwise-and-of-all-numbers-for-a-given-range

**EDIT 2:** Here is my code, I have not tested it extensively but it seems to work. (O(log(n))

```
from math import log

for case in [[i+1,j+i+1] for i in range(30) for j in range(30)]:
    #Get input
    l, u = case


    invL=2**int(log(l,2)+1)-l
    invU=2**int(log(u,2)+1)-u


    #Calculate pseudo bitwise xnor of input and format to binary rep
    e=format((u&l | invL & invU),'010b')
    lBin=format(l,'010b')
    #output to zero
    res=0

    #boolean to check if we have found any zero
    anyZero=False

    #boolean to check the first one because we have leading zeros
    firstOne=False

    for ind,i in enumerate(e):
        #for every digit

        #if it is a leading one
        if i=='1' and (not anyZero):
            firstOne=True
            #leftshift result (multiply by 2)
            res=res<<1
            #and add 1
            res=res+int(lBin[ind])
        #else if we already had a one and find a zero this happens every time
        elif(firstOne):
            anyZero=True
            #leftshift
            res=res<<1
    #test if we are in the same power, if not there was a power between

    if(res!=0):
        #print "test",(int(log(res,2))!=int(log(l,2))) | ((log(res,2))!=int(log(u,2)))
        if((int(log(res,2))!=int(log(l,2))) or (int(log(res,2))!=int(log(u,2)))):
            res=0

    print res
```

[image]

Worked for every but a single testcase. Small change needed to get the last one. You'll have to find out what that small change is yourself. Seriously

Comment: I have changed the code but it now shows wrong answer! @JeD

Comment: @Myni in your first if it should be `int(log(u,2))!=int(log(l,2))` instead of `int(log(l,2))!=int(log(l,2))` ;)

Comment: @Myni yeah you were right :/
Alright tested new answer for 9000 cases and worked. If it still fails I give up -__-

Comment: My dear @JeD.... It doesn't even pass the sample testcase, it just goes haywire....

Comment: You do see that I removed raw_input from the for loop right? @Myni